# How to properly call destructors when exiting within a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Context:

I'm working with with a project composed simplistically of three layers, an application layer, an interface layer, and a middleware layer. The interface layer provides additional functionality on top of the middleware layer, and is responsible for managing threads running the middleware application.

My issue is that to exit the program, interrupt signals are used, the handler for these signals is defined at the lowest, middleware layer. When an interrupt signal is sent, the handler eventually calls `exit(0)`, which results in an interface-layer destructor being called by the same thread calling `exit(0)`. Within this destructor, `middlewareAppThread.join()`is called, resulting in a deadlock as the thread is trying to join itself.

This is a simplified representation, sorry if it's messy:

[image]

What confuses me is seeing how the Proxy object is referenced in the global namespace, I thought the destructor would be called by the main thread, but when debugging it's apparent the destructor is called by `middlewareAppThread`.

The solution I've thought of so far is to remove the signal handler from the middleware stack, and create one in the app/interface layer. This is a little problematic as the middleware is third-party. **Is there a way to keep the `exit(0)` call at the lowest level, with the destructors being called from the main thread?**

Or: What could be causing the destructor to be called from the `middlewareAppThread`?

Comment: You can call `exit` only if current thread is the only one running. Must signal threads to finish, and `join` them before calling `exit`. Must NOT join threads from destructors.

Comment: Don't use `exit()` would be my general advise. Don't use globals would be another advise. Use dependency injection to distribute shared objects between different parts of your code. Use a coordinated shutdown that waits for threads to finish.

Comment: This is typical of what happens when a,non-trivial app attempts a 'graceful termination'.  Is there some important reason why you cannot just terminate the process?

Comment: @MartinJames Yeah, the destructors are responsible for closing/deleting a lockfile used to check if an instance of the app is already running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the thread that calls [`exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/exit) that does all of the cleanup.

> Several cleanup steps are performed:
>
> 1. The destructors of objects with thread local storage duration *that are associated with the current thread*, the destructors of objects with static storage duration, and the functions registered with std::atexit are executed concurrently

(emphasis added)

> I thought the destructor would be called by the main thread

What makes you think that? C++ does not associate objects with threads. Even a *thread local* object can be interacted with on another thread through a pointer or reference.

> Is there a way to keep the `exit(0)` call at the lowest level

Yes, don't have static duration `std::thread` (sub-)objects, especially those which can call `exit`.

> with the destructors being called from the main thread?

Co-ordinate such that the main thread is the one to call `exit`. Or just return from `main`

Comment: Thanks, I thought objects were associated with the threads somehow. I think I'll go with the first solution and set up a handler in the main thread to return on interrupt. I'm a bit annoyed at how the code is currently structured, as both layers are written by the same corporation and are intended to be used with each other.